# rally : how to get "description" attribute of a testcase from testcaseresult

Tags: rally, testcase

I am querying for a testcaseresult and I want to print the "name" and "description" attributes of testcase, this testcaseresult belongs to. So I am using the following code to make a query.

```
var queryObject = {
                        type : 'TestCaseResult',
                        key : 'tcresults',
                        fetch: 'Build,Name,TestSet,Verdict,TestCase,Date'
                    };
```

From this query, I can get TestCase.Name ,but not TestCase.Description.
Do I have to do a separate query for the testcase to access "Description" or is there something I am missing over here? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on my earlier answer. Have you tried adding Description to your fetch: 'Build,Name,TestSet,Verdict,TestCase,Date,Description'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to "fetch" description, too?

fetch: 'Build,Name,TestSet,Verdict,TestCase,Date,Description'